# How to show a response when filtering through a list of elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I am creating an FAQ page that has to be filtered using javascript as below

**Credit : https://makitweb.com/jquery-search-text-in-the-element-with-contains-selector/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#filter').keyup(function () {

    // Search text
    var text = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    var error = document.getElementById("error");

    // Hide all content class element
    $('.mobrog-ux-text').hide();

    // Search 
    $('.mobrog-ux-text').each(function () {


      if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf("" + text + "") != -1) {
        $(this).closest('.mobrog-ux-text').show();
        setTimeout(
          function () {
            var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
            x.style.display = "none";

          }, 4000);
   
        error.style.display = "none";
      }

else if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf("" + text + "") == 0) {

      error.style.display = "block";
}

    });
  });
});

<form align="center">
        <input id="filter" onkeydown="keydownFunction()" oninput="keyPress(this.value)" class="searchfield" type="text"
          name="search" placeholder="Search the help center">
      </form>

      <div style="color: white;padding : 10px" align="center"></div>

    </div>

    <div class="content2">
      <h2>Frequently asked questions</h2>
      <div id"pag"="id" pag""="pag" ""></div>

      <div align="center" class="col-10">
        <div class="mobrog-tab-container maxwidth">

          <div id="myDIV" class="loader"></div>

          <div class="error" id="error"> No result found!!</div>
          <div id="results" class="mobrog-ux-vertical-tabs">
            <div id="tar" class="mobrog-tabs">
              <button data-tab="tab1" class="active">sample tab button?<span></span></button>
          

              <button class="empty"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="mobrog-maincontent">
              <div data-tab="tab1" class="mobrog-tabcontent active">

                <div class="mobrog-ux-text">
                  <button class="mobrog-accordion">sample button</button>
                  <div class="mobrog-panel">
                    <p>
                    sample text
                    </p>
                    
                  </div>

                </div>
```

Which works, but then I am trying to show a message when the filtered word is not found within the list of DIVS I'm searching through on my FAQ page

I tried the below with

```
  else if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf("" + text + "") == 0) {
//error message display

}
```

But then it does not work

**(e.g when I type in a word which does not exist within my FAQ I want to display an error message which is in a div) and vice versa when the word is found in my FAQ page)**

like the way its been used in the method of RegExp
**[Live search on an Div with input filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44736054/live-search-on-an-div-with-input-filter)**

**at the moment when I type in available and unavailable words the error message appears**

Please how do I effectively display a message when a filtered word is found or not found

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for heads up, I have adjusted the description @Wyck

Comment: _when I type in available and unavailable words the error message appears_.  This description of the problem is exceedingly brief.  I know _you_ know what's happening, but we can't see from here.  It's especially important to be descriptive since your example is not a self-contained stand-alone demonstration (requires jquery and unknown markup)  Maybe put it all in a runnable snippet?

Comment: I think your biggest issue is that the error is being shown if any result doesn't match. I would suggest having a variable (outside the loop) which is set to false, then set it to true on any match. After the loop, you can use this variable to show/hide the error

Comment: thank you @Rylee I did exactly as you instructed and it has worked. for the sake of others who might have this issue can you make your explanation an answer so I can vote it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, this is an example of how you could implement something like this.

To reiterate - the main problem was that the error was being shown if *any* result didn't match instead of showing if *none* match

To fix that, we can add a variable outside the loop to determine if any result was matched

```js
$(document)
    .ready(function () {
        $('#filter')
            .keyup(function () {
                // Search text
                var text  = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                var error = document.getElementById("error");
                
                // storing this in a variable will reduce how many times you call the function
                var $ux_texts = $('.mobrog-ux-text');

                // Hide all content class element
                $ux_texts.hide();
                
                // variable to update if any match is found
                var has_match = false;

                // Search 
                $ux_texts
                    .each(function () {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        if ($this.text().toLowerCase().indexOf("" + text + "") === -1) {
                            // flip the logic so we can return early - makes for cleaner code
                            return;
                        }

                        $this.closest('.mobrog-ux-text').show();
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
                            x.style.display = "none";
                        }, 4000);

                        has_match = true;
                    });

                // error handling
                if (has_match) {
                    error.style.display = "none";
                } else {
                    error.style.display = "block";
                }
            });
    });
```